# Change Mysql column Value

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have two question

at first:

we have Table `user` with column `usergroupid`". I want to find all "2" values in this column and change to "1"

and second question:

How can I do change the value only for id's 100 > end, not do the change for first 100 id's

User id's Column name `userid`

Comment: Confusing; please explain what you are asking actually.

Comment: because i want to migrate two database togeather :D and i needed to change feq id's before migrate :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming userid are sequential and starts from 1, if you want to update usergroupid from 2 to 1 to the greater than 100 id you can try this

```
UPDATE user
SET usergroupid = 1
WHERE usergroupid = 2
AND userid > 100
```